# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autoreload'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I run the following code from convolutional neural network tutorials on jupyter notebook with python 3 kernel, and got the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autoreload';

```
import numpy as np
import h5py          
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (5.0, 4.0) # set default size of plots
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'

%load_ext autoreload   
%autoreload 2          
np.random.seed(1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3d0ea63c7843> in <module>()
      8 plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'
      9 
---> 10 get_ipython().magic('load_ext autoreload   # reload modules before executing user code')
     11 get_ipython().magic('autoreload 2          # Reload all modules (except those excluded by %aimport)')
     12 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in magic(self, arg_s)
   2156         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2157         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2158         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2159 
   2160     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2077                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2078             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2079                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2080             return result
   2081 

<decorator-gen-62> in load_ext(self, module_str)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.py in load_ext(self, module_str)
     35         if not module_str:
     36             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
---> 37         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
     38 
     39         if res == 'already loaded':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py in load_extension(self, module_str)
     81             if module_str not in sys.modules:
     82                 with prepended_to_syspath(self.ipython_extension_dir):
---> 83                     __import__(module_str)
     84             mod = sys.modules[module_str]
     85             if self._call_load_ipython_extension(mod):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autoreload'
```

I just couldn't find any solution on this issue. How should I fix this error?

Comment: This is simply an import error (cloaked in magic). I would guess that `import autoreload` also fails for you. There is something wrong with your python path. The there should by an `autoreload.py` somewhere in your path, usually in something like `.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions`. Look for something similar in `sys.path`.

Comment: Actually, I found the autoreload.py as per your advice. It's in the ...\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions. What else might be the cause or what should I do next?

Comment: Can you load the module directly with `import autoreload`?

Is the extensions folder in sys.path?

Answer (score 25):

The module autoreload belongs to the library IPython, which is running in the background on Jupyter.

The same error occurred to me and it was due to a blank space, see:

[image: snippet code].

So **make sure that there are no spaces at the end of the command**!

Comment: Wow! Yes! I have spent a lot of time trying to understand why `import autoreload` works and why `%load_ext autoreload` does not. And it seems like the magic lines are read differently from standard python line! I had indeed a space at the end of the line after autoreload!

Comment: What an annoying error! I was just stuck with this as well, thanks for pointing me in the right direction - the trailing space is indeed a problem with ipython magics

Comment: @Luís Eduardo, Thanks. This was indeed the issue. It was difficult to see why there was a problem because all I had after the line magic was (a space followed by) a comment which I thought would not be processed by the interpreter.

Answer (score 14):

I hit this same error because I had a comment after the magic command:

bad:

```
%load_ext autoreload # this comment should be removed
```

good:

```
%load_ext autoreload
```

Comment: I'v found that even just leaving a space after `%load_ext autoreload` will cause the error.

Comment: I can confirmed the behavior @Nayef is describing, I had a trailing white space and got the same error.